# React Native ios compiler throws multiple warnings in version 072.3. Is it a bug?

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

Does anyone know why, when using RN 0.72.3, the ios compiler throws dozens of ios warnings? For example, multiple pods have warnings like these:

```
/Pods/libevent/include/event2/bufferevent.h:220:11: parameter 'evdns_base' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]

   @param evdns_base Optionally, an evdns_base to use for resolving hostnames

/Pods/libevent/include/event2/bufferevent_compat.h:59:4: declaration is marked with '@deprecated' command but does not have a deprecation attribute [-Wdocumentation-deprecated-sync]
```

I've tried completely removing node_modules and pods (using `pod deintegrate && pod setup && pod install --repo-update` with no apparent effect. The compiler also completes with this output:

```
⚠️  ld: duplicate symbol 'folly::detail::str_to_bool(folly::Range<char const*>*)' in:
⚠️  ld: duplicate symbol 'folly::makeConversionError(folly::ConversionCode, folly::Range<char const*>)' in:
⚠️  ld: duplicate symbol 'folly::exception_wrapper::from_exception_ptr(std::exception_ptr&&)' in:
⚠️  ld: duplicate symbol 'folly::exception_wrapper::from_exception_ptr(std::exception_ptr const&)' in:
⚠️  ld: duplicate symbol 'folly::exception_wrapper::onNoExceptionError(char const*)' in:
⚠️  ld: duplicate symbol 'folly::exceptionStr(folly::exception_wrapper const&)' in:
```

Has any seen this behavior and/or have a possible explanation? Is it a known bug? Is there a fix or workaround? Should I be concerned? My app compiles and runs, but this new behavior bothers me.